# Why am I getting docker@postgres ERROR: relation "accounts_myprofile" does not exist?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, postgis

So I am working on a project Django/Postgres project.

When I run docker-compose up, the project launches with Django in one container and Postgres in the other.  I am able to view certain URL's of my project, however the ones that query MyProfile model, all result in the following error:

```
docker@postgres ERROR:  relation "accounts_myprofile" does not exist
```

I have ran both:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations
```

and:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but this returns with:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cities, contenttypes, django_messages, easy_thumbnails, guardian, sessions, sites, userena
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Attaching my docker-compose and Django settings below.

docker-compose

```
web:

  restart: always

  build: ./web

  expose:

    - "8000"

  links:

    - postgres:postgres


  volumes:

    - /usr/src/app

    - /usr/src/app/static

  env_file: .env

  environment:

    DEBUG: 'true'

  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000


postgres:

  restart: always

  image: kartoza/postgis:9.4-2.1

  ports:

    - "5432:5432"

  volumes:

    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image
from django_resized import ResizedImageField
import datetime

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='my_profile')
    storename=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    streetaddress=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips1=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips2=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips3=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips4=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips5=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nearbyzips6=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=16)
    websiteurl=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=38)
    deliveryoption=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    storebio=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    storespecials=models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=65)
    reviewavg=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=5)
    coverpic = ResizedImageField(max_width=350, upload_to="site_media/media/covers/", null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.user, self.storename, self.streetaddress, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode, self.storebio, self.reviewavg)


class Entry(models.Model):
    headline= models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='entryauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    zipcode =models.IntegerField(null=True)
    entrytype = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price3 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    price4 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    price5 = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    item_picture = ResizedImageField(max_width=400, upload_to="site_media/media/items/")

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.headline, self.body_text, self.author, self.pub_date, self.zipcode, self.price1, self.price2)
```

views.py (only included the functions with queries that trigger error)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.forms import UserReviewForm
from accounts.forms import SellForm
from accounts.models import Entry
from accounts.models import UserReview
from accounts.models import MyProfile
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import json as simplejson
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
from userena import settings as userena_settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from userena.utils import signin_redirect, get_profile_model, get_user_model
from userena.views import ExtraContextTemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django_messages.models import inbox_count_for
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from accounts.serializers import EntrySerializer


def storefront(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.my_profile.zipcode:
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=[request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips1,
            request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips2,
            request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips3,
            request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips4,
            request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips5]).order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
            unread_list = inbox_count_for(request.user)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries, 'unread_list': unread_list}        
        else:
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
    else:
        latest_entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:16]
        context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries} 
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'new':
            latest_entries = latest_entries.filter(entrytype=1)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'old':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=2)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
        if request.GET.get('filter') == 'oklder':
            latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(entrytype=3)
            context = {'latest_entries': latest_entries}
            return render(request, 'storefrontload.html', context)
    return render(request, 'storefront.html', context)
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))  
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
DEBUG=True    

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DB_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DB_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_SERVICE'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

SITE_ID = int(os.environ.get("SITE_ID", 1))

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static1")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade this project which was made on Django 1.6 to 1.10 so I'm guessing something changed in 1.10 that breaks my project but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: TL:DR.   [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Django 1.8 introduced a new db migration system to replace South. Since you are trying to upgrade from 1.6, you also need to upgrade your South migration files.

Comment: I never migrated any over.  I removed the migrations folder

Comment: I am trying move this project over to 1.10 but with a fresh db if that makes sense.

Comment: You can use `django-admin showmigrations --plan` to get a list of applied migrations. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, post the output of the `makemigrations` and `showmigrations` commands. Also the content of the generated migration file could be relevant. Unfortunately, solving issues with migrations in Django can be quite confusing, and it can be hard to create a [mcve].

Comment: The error message you get is because there are changes to the models that have not been applied to the database with a migration. Specifically there doesn't seem to be any migrations for the `accounts` app. You could try `makemigrations accounts`.

Comment: Haken you were right, but makemigrations did not work for some reason when calling with docker-compose, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason running:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations accounts

docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate accounts
```

Returned with this

```
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied
```

But when actually going into the Django container and directly running

```
python manage.py makemigrations accounts
python manage.py migrate accounts
```

This worked and my project is now completely working without database errors.

So my issue is resolved but I couldn't tell you why running this command with docker-compose does not seem to work for me.